# TERADATA comma separated column comparison

Tags: sql, teradata

I am facing below issue in Teradata 15.10.03.01. This is regarding the comma separated column comparison. Consider the data mentioned below and expected result.

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 ,NO FALLBACK ,
         NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
         NO AFTER JOURNAL,
         CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
         DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
         (
          A VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          B VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          C VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
    PRIMARY INDEX ( A );

    CREATE MULTISET TABLE TESTDB.TESTTABLE2 ,NO FALLBACK ,
         NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
         NO AFTER JOURNAL,
         CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
         DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
         (
          A VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          B VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
          C VARCHAR(250) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC)
    PRIMARY INDEX ( A );



    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 VALUES('A1','B1','C1');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 VALUES('A2','B2','C2');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 VALUES('A3',NULL,'C3');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 VALUES('A4',NULL,'C4');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 VALUES(NULL,'B5','C5');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 VALUES(NULL,'B6','C6');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 VALUES(NULL,NULL,'C7');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 VALUES(NULL,NULL,'C8');

    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE2 VALUES('A1','B1','C1');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE2 VALUES('A3',NULL,'C3');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE2 VALUES(NULL,'B5','C5');
    INSERT INTO TESTDB.TESTTABLE2 VALUES(NULL,NULL,'C7');

    SELECT * FROM TESTDB.TESTTABLE1;

    A    B     C
   -------------
    A1   B1    C1
    A2   B2    C2
    A3         C3
    A4         C4
         B5    C5
         B6    C6
               C7
               C8

    SELECT * FROM  TESTDB.TESTTABLE2;          
    A    B     C
    ------------     
    A1   B1    C1
    A3         C3
         B5    C5
               C7
```

EXPECTED RESULT:

```
    A    B     C
   -------------
    A2   B2    C2
    A4         C3
         B6    C6
```

I tried with the below query but its returning no records.

```
    SELECT T1.A,T1.B,T1.C
    FROM TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 T1
    WHERE (T1.A,T1.B)
    NOT IN
    (
    SELECT T2.A,T2.B
    FROM TESTDB.TESTTABLE2 T2
    )
    ;
```

How can I frame the query?

Why are my query returning no records?

Comment: (Most of this question is presented as one monolithic code block, the `below issue` not apparent without scrolling. Please take the time to get an idea [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).)

Answer (score 3):

There's some info in the manuals: [Behavior of Nulls for NOT IN](http://www.info.teradata.com/htmlpubs/DB_TTU_15_10/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035_1145_151K/behavior_of_nulls_for_not_in_IN_NOT_IN.html), but afaik this behavior is not correct according to Standard SQL.

Your query should return no rows as any comparison to `NULL` results in `UNKNOWN`, thus a single NULL returned by the subquery will result in an empty result.

So simply follow the basic recomendation for every DBMS, **never use `NOT IN` for NULLable columns**.

The usual rewrite is based on `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT T1.A,T1.B,T1.C
FROM TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT *
FROM TESTDB.TESTTABLE2 T2
WHERE T1.A = T2.A
  AND T1.B = T2.B
)
;
```

But in your case this will also not return your expected result because NULL is not equal to NULL.

You need a set operation, `EXCEPT` (or `MINUS`), which treats NULLs equal:

```
SELECT * FROM TESTDB.TESTTABLE1
EXCEPT
SELECT * FROM TESTDB.TESTTABLE2
```

Edit:

The `EXCEPT` might not provide the correct result because it compares all three columns instead of two, it's working for your example data but might fail for your real data.

There's the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40401285/2527905) from @DavidCram using `COALESCE` (of course you need to pick a value which is guaranteed not to exists), another is based on an Outer Join, but you need a column which is defined a `NOT NULL` in he 2nd table:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM TESTDB.TESTTABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TESTDB.TESTTABLE2 T2
  ON (T1.A = T2.A OR (T1.A IS NULL AND T2.A IS NULL))
 AND (T1.B = T2.B OR (T1.B IS NULL AND T2.B IS NULL))
WHERE T2.C IS NULL
;
```

This avoids `COALESCE` and might still join on a Primary Index.

Answer (score 1):

You need to coalesce your nulls when you compare them

```
SELECT T1.A,T1.B,T1.C
FROM TESTTABLE1 T1
WHERE (COALESCE(T1.A,''),COALESCE(T1.B,''))
NOT IN
(
SELECT COALESCE(T2.A,''),COALESCE(T2.B,'')
FROM TESTTABLE2 T2
)
;
```

Comment: Actually, I like dnoeth's answer better but I will leave mine here since it works :-).  Also in your expected result, I think you say C3 where you mean C4 (based on what is actually in your test tables)

Comment: In fact, my answer will probably not work as the EXCEPT is based on all three columns, while the NOT IN was based on two :)

Comment: Oh well,  you still got an upvote from me because your answer explained the issues with null very clearly and I am also not a fan of using "NOT IN" for this sort of thing